# Is there anyway to transfer .war or .jar from one server to another with Hudson?

Tags: linux, continuous-integration, hudson, scp, hudson-plugins

I am using Hudson and wondering if is there anyway to transfer one file(this file is on a Linux Server)to another linux server.

Maybe use scp command from linux, just wanna know if somebody already did this, and maybe point me to the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your hudson job? Sure, you could use scp in an "execute shell" build step. For getting this to work you probably need to have public-key authentication setup between the two hosts, IIRC scp does not allow you to specify a password.

There are also several plugins for copying build artifacts to other systems (see http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/All+Plugins+by+Topic#AllPluginsbyTopic-Artifactuploaders), for instance there is an scp artifact archiver.

Answer (score 2):

The [SCP plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCP+plugin) should fit your needs.

It lets you choose between using a key or username/ password. Destinations are configured in the central Hudson/ Jenkins config, then you can choose a destination to upload to in a specific job.  And in the job you can specify a pattern matching the desired file(s) to upload.

Comment: Nice, im using this plugin already to send files to some servers, but this plugin is taking the file from the workspace. Maybe if instead of taking from the workspace i could take the file from a linux server, this should work perfectly

Comment: ah - didn't catch that nuance.  you could let a script command copy the file into the workspace first (more robust), or just create a symlink within the workspace to containing directory outside the workspace (quicker but more fragile, since workspace can be cleaned when not just updating incrementally from SCM).